# Electricity and light bulbs

Tags: visible-light, electric-current, lightning

Kindly say if I am right?

**Case1:**  *Current flow and light from an incandescent bulb.*
 
Reason for light due to current flow:  Tungsten is an insulator (comparatively) so when sufficiently high potential difference applied across it, its bonds are broken and that bond energy is what is manifested as light. 
But how does it maintain emitting light without melting? It has a very high melting point. But why?

**Case2:** *Current through copper wire puts out no light.* 
It is a conductor and the potential energy difference is used to move electrons. But if higher potential energy is applied, its bonds also break and it releases energy as light, but as it has a lower melting point, it melts.

**Case3:**  *Light in fluorescent tubes*
The potential difference applied between cathode and anode causes bond breakage of air which is an insulator. And this energy manifests as light. This is the same as the lightning phenomenon.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! It is my opinion that your question seems somewhat broad and unclear. It would be helpful to focus on a single problem, and to specifically describe the physics concept you are struggling with.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that you're not right.

Bond breakage is not relevant in any of your three cases.

Cases 1 and 2. Tungsten is a metal and therefore a good conductor of electricity, though not as good as copper. The reason that metals conduct electricity is that they contain 'free electrons' that have no particular attachment to any atom. When a voltage is applied across the end of the wire, these electrons are urged through the wire. They bump into the atoms (strictly ions) in the wire and make them vibrate more vigorously. This raises the temperature of the wire. In a vacuum the tungsten can get white hot if the voltage is high enough, because of its high melting point. Copper will probably only get red hot before it melts.

Case 3. In a fluorescent (note spelling!) tube, fast moving electrons are sent through the tube. They knock into mercury atoms at high speed, sometimes ionising them (knocking an electron out) and sometimes just raising the energy levels of electrons attached to the atom. When the ions recapture electrons, or electrons drop down to lower energy levels, photons of light but mainly of ultraviolet are emitted. Chemicals coating the inside of the glass tube take in the ultraviolet and give out visible light ('fluorescence').

I'm sorry if this is more complicated than you wanted, but it's difficult to make it any simpler while retaining any semblance of correctness. Even so, I expect some criticism for oversimplification!

Comment: FWIW, Most modern incandescent light bulbs are not fully evacuated; They contain an [inert fill gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incandescent_light_bulb#Gas_fill) at slightly less than atmospheric pressure.  White-hot tungsten doesn't melt, but it slowly sublimes, and in total vacuum, the hot tungsten atoms condense on the the inner surface of the glass envelope, and turn it dark.  I don't fully understand how, but the fill gas slows that process down enough that the glass stays mostly clear throughout the entire life of the filament.

Comment: Yes indeed. I warned the reader that what I'd written was oversimplified. I believe that the tungsten-halogen lamp takes things one stage further, in that the sublimed tungsten atoms combine with the halogen in the cooler regions away from the filament, but if convection takes the resultant molecules into the hot region next to the filament, they are likely to dissociate, re-depositing tungsten on the filament!